# Can I link to a post from Q&A in documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I was planning to improve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/1853/reserved-keywords/16733/identifiers-identifier-names#t=20161219173320754396) example, which talks about `Identifier`s and `IdentifierName`s in JavaScript. I was wondering, is it okay to link to an answer of mine, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40209367/do-reserved-words-need-to-be-quoted-when-set-as-property-names-of-javascript-obj/40210179#40210179) one, that explains this in detail or is there a better way to connect a Q&A question to documentation?

Side-note: The example currently could benefit from the explanation in my opinion, but is it really necessary in the first place?

Comment: Since it's your answer, just copy the content to Documentation. If you want to give yourself credit by linking back to the answer, feel free. Side-note: I think that topic should be deleted. A list of things easily found elsewhere does not a good example make, and the example regarding `Identifier`s should probably be under a different topic.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Ok, and agreed about the list. Where should the other one be moved to?

Comment: Not sure. I didn't see one after a brief look at existing topics. Maybe a new Syntax topic? Or even base it on the standard and call it "Lexical Conventions", because it rolls off the tongue so well :)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's fine to link to answers, including your own.

Really, it's fine to link anything - but just [like in Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/130213), links should be supplementary not the only content.